# How to keep track of number of rows inserted or updated in a table in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS for ETL and I need to know how to keep track of the number of records being inserted and updated in a table.

The thing is, in SSIS during the packages is running we will be able to see the number of records processed and no of records being updated or inserted but 
**how to save them to a log file or in any other documents** so that we can keep track of it for future references???.

Thanks in advance.

Jeevan kumar

Answer (score 2):

You may include a `RecordCount` task in your flow to set a variable with the number of rows passing this point. Later save the variables values into your log file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will try doing that and will come back if I have any other concern.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at 'triggers in SSMS'. and then use 'output' to log the inserts and updates.